# Geopandas: overlay(how="union") can't handle more than one geometry columns

Tags: python, geopandas

**Goal:** Merge country polygons from Natural Earth with the disputed areas. So that I have undisputed and disputed areas in one geodataframe

**Code:**

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gpd.read_file("ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp").overlay(gpd.read_file("ne_50m_admin_0_breakaway_disputed_areas.shp"), how="union")
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: GeoDataFrame does not support multiple columns using the geometry column name 'geometry'.
```

**Question:** Is this a bug or am I missing something? It seems like a logical thing to have two `geometry`-columns when merging two geodataframes. I'm using the regular NE-files fresh from their site: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a really a bug in GeoPandas but in Pandas: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2544

The bug has been fixed in a newer version of Pandas. A simple `pip install pandas --upgrade` has fixed it for me.